# Created table does not appear in pgAdmin4 side bar

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I created a table with the query editor in pgAdmin4, added some data and I can select entries from that table. However, pgAdmin does not show that new table anywhere in the side bar under Schemas/Tables. Where else should I look?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Refresh the schema and the table will get reloaded

Answer (score 0):

Select the database and navigate to Object/Refresh. Then the new table appears in the side bar.